# Change title of the default page of PWA site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, pwa

I need to change the title of default page of PWA site. I would to do it via UI by editing page. But this option in not available.

Then I try to edit the default.aspx via SPD, but have an error :

> This web site has been configured to disallow page editing with SPD

My last variant is to add js on the page and edit `DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea`

Is it the only way to resolve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The occurrence of this issue could be due to...**

- SharePoint Designer might be disallowed to be used in this  Web Application.
- By default, Web design features are disabled in `ONET.XML` file.

> For more details, Please Check [This web site has been configured to disallow editing with SharePoint Designer 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/this-web-site-has-been-configured-to-disallow-editing-with-sharepoint-designer/)

Answer (score -3):

Please go to PWA Settings-> Project Detail Pages and choose page to edit.
On page tab choose Edit Properties. There is option to change Display name of default PWA page.